# to download schematic.plot package in r

Tags: r

I am trying to schematic plot of txt data but when I write schematic.plot there is no package in Rstudio. I am searching for the package but it is not downloading.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install a package in Rstudio you would want to run the command to in the console as follows:

```r
install.packages("BiocManager")
```

To install ELMER as this package contains the schematic.plot function I believe you are looking for we actually install it using bioconductors installer as follows:

```r
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("ELMER")
```

Please let me know if this isn't what you're looking for and I'll try to improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to do:

```
install.packages("ELMER")
library(ELMER)
```

to get the package in there.

Comment: This method doesn't due to it being a bioconductor package